# why mysql change my code view?

Tags: mysql

I create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `idtable1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtable1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `idtable2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idtable1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `table2col1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `table2col2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtable2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW `view1` AS
select t2.* 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.idtable1 = t2.idtable1
```

when complie mysql change my code:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view1` AS
    select 
        `t2`.`idtable2` AS `idtable2`,
        `t2`.`idtable1` AS `idtable1`,
        `t2`.`table2col1` AS `table2col1`,
        `t2`.`table2col2` AS `table2col2`
    from
        (`table1` `t1`
        join `table2` `t2`)
    where
        (`t1`.`idtable1` = `t2`.`idtable1`)
```

there any way to avoid this behavior?

here is another example, no answer:
[Why is mysql rewriting my view queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526127/why-is-mysql-rewriting-my-view-queries)

mysql adds unnecessary parenthesis and put the code on one line.

Even when using the correct syntax mysql change the view adding unnecessary parentheses.

Original:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view2` AS
    select 
        `t2`.`idtable2` AS `idtable2`,
        `t2`.`idtable1` AS `idtable1`,
        `t2`.`table2col1` AS `table2col1`,
        `t2`.`table2col2` AS `table2col2`
    from
        `table1` `t1` 
         left join `table2` `t2` on  `t1`.`idtable1` = `t2`.`idtable1`
```

Compiled:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view2` AS
    select 
        `t2`.`idtable2` AS `idtable2`,
        `t2`.`idtable1` AS `idtable1`,
        `t2`.`table2col1` AS `table2col1`,
        `t2`.`table2col2` AS `table2col2`
    from
        (`table1` `t1`
        left join `table2` `t2` ON ((`t1`.`idtable1` = `t2`.`idtable1`)))
```

Comment: It's rewriting it in proper SQL.

Comment: The code is equivalent.  I find it surprising that MySQL is using *improper* SQL for the rewrite -- the `where` clause should be an `on` clause.  In fact, you should just write the original view using proper `join` syntax.

Comment: my problem is that even when using the correct format mysql change the view adding parentheses and new lines. I've always used sql server and this never happens.

Comment: Why MySQL changes your view source I can't answer, but I believe that the rewritten query is how MySQL interprets your query anyway.

Comment: What version of MySQL is this?

Comment: 5.6.14-log Mysql Community Server (GPL)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you will find that whenever the ON is converted to a WHERE, there is no effect on the resultset generated.  Notice that with the LEFT, it kept it as ON.  The optimizer will come along later and do whatever it feels like, so why does it matter that the VIEW does not look like what you started with?

Comment: @RickJames . . . I consider it bad that the database does not store the original text of the `create` statement.  For instance, I have used comments in views and stored procedures (on occasion) to store additional information.  Also, MySQL should rewrite the code using standard SQL, when it can.  A `join` without an `on` won't work in any other database -- and perhaps one day in future versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is issues resulting from the SQL being compiled and then decompiled.

```
human readable SQL -> compiled form -> human readable SQL
```

Don't worry, it's all equivalent code.  If you want an example, write some JSON by hand, run it through a JSON parser, then turn that data back into JSON.  It won't look the same as the original.

This is a common problem in converting data known as "round tripping".  Without extra work, non-semantic information like comments, indentation, and parenthesis (or the lack of them) is lost.  MySQL may also apply optimizations and semantic transformations, such as turning your FROM/WHERE into a JOIN.  Its also making implicit code and defaults (such as `ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED`) explicit.

Seeing the result of a round trip can help you spot subtle bugs in your code, especially about order of operations.  A decompiler can sometimes be asked to add extra parenthesis to make the order obvious.

There's no point in MySQL storing your original CREATEs for tables and views, they become useless if ALTER is used.  However, returning your queries as originally written may be possible.

Comment: I had not realized that it also removes comments. That's a big problem for me, because I need to add documentation. You know how to configure mysql to store my original code?

Comment: @quimmo I doubt it can. What would it do with a table that has been altered? You shouldn't use the database as your canonical source of schema information for exactly this reason. It used to be worse, MySQL used to not store foreign key information (it had the syntax but didn't do anything with it).  Your schema should be in a code repository.

Comment: You're right, the only way to access the original code is reading the .frm file. Here is the answer: [link](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=D0b_Xg3UeXEC&pg=PT516&lpg=PT516&dq=mysql+original+view&source=bl&ots=R_Nh1XEySF&sig=R9fKlRea91nBPTLOiaW1Xe2pLN0&hl=es&sa=X&ei=NC_mVNzUNJCryQSvs4CgBw&ved=0CGUQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=mysql%20original%20view&f=false)

Comment: @quimmo Consider a tool like [Sqitch](http://sqitch.org/) for schema change management.