# MariaDB create view changes the SELECT to a different (incorrect) query

Tags: sql, sum, mariadb, sql-view

I have a query I would like as a view in MariaDB 10.3(win), however when I attempt to create such view it is being changed to a different (and incorrect) one, removing parentheses:

```
create or replace view v_ReceiptSumByVAT
as
select VAT, SUM(RetailPrice) / (1 + VAT) as Sum from ReceiptItem
  group by VAT
```

when I run the `SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION` later, the returned query is (note missing parentheses near VAT)

```
select VAT, SUM(RetailPrice) / 1 + VAT as Sum from ReceiptItem
  group by VAT
```

which gives different results than the original SELECT query - `A / 1 + B` is not equal to `A / (1 + B)` ! 
 I have found a similar question [why mysql change my code view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612175/why-mysql-change-my-code-view) that however deals with MySql and the query being changed to equivalent, not a different one. How can I ensure the view gets created correctly?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour in MySQL, so I'd be tempted to remove that tag.

Comment: This can be replicated in MariaDB:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2ad57cb0609332d1b4605c65b37adf50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, seems like a bug, consider reporting that to the project... As a workaround you can try to use a derived table only doing the aggregation and an outer query that then does the arithmetic operations on the sum.

```
CREATE VIEW v_receiptsumbyvat
AS
SELECT vat,
       sum / (vat + 1) sum
       FROM (SELECT vat,
                    sum(retailprice) sum
                    FROM receiptitem
             GROUP BY vat) x;
```

At least on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=1a415d0e5b42a604501b7ed3711cf832) that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in MariaDB server.

For status please check [MDEV-23656](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23656) in MariaDB's bug ticket system

Answer (score 0):

change your query like this and see your result

```
  create or replace view v_ReceiptSumByVAT
  as
  select ROUND(VAT, 1 / (1 + VAT) * SUM(RetailPrice)) as Sum from ReceiptItem
  group by VAT
```

in MySQL/MariaDB the view removes the parenthesis if the expression is specified after the function so specify exp before the function. it works

Comment: Even though it do not indeed remove the parentheses AND it is consistent with with corresponding select, it does give yet another different result - it is probably less stable calculation. For sum = 120 and VAT 0.20 the expencted value of sum without VAT is 100, this reversed query, however return 99.996 instead.  The original reference query gives 100 exact.

Comment: use the ROUND function around the expression like above , then it should work.